# Dataset.map() throws ClassCastException while running in yarn-client mode from eclipse, but pass in local mode

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, dataset, classcastexception

You may think it as duplicate issue, but I have tried everything found on Internet. Please help me in this.

I have this simple class.

```
public class TestClassCastException {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn")
                .setAppName("Testing Class Cast Exception")
                .set("deploy-mode", "client");


        System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "huser");
        SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf)
                .getOrCreate();
        Dataset<Row> jsonData = session.read().json("file:///home/jrp/workspace_1/Spark21-Example/input-data/people.json");
        jsonData.show();
        /*
        +----+-------+
        | age|   name|
        +----+-------+
        |  32|Michael|
        |  60|   Andy|
        |  19| Justin|
        +----+-------+
        */

        jsonData.printSchema();
        /*
        root
         |-- age: long (nullable = true)
         |-- name: string (nullable = true)
        */


        Dataset<String> citizens = jsonData.map(new MapFunction<Row, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(Row row) throws Exception {
                if (row.getLong(0) >= 60) {
                    return row.getString(1) + " : Senior Citizen";
                }
                return row.getString(1) + " : Non-Senior";
            }
        }, Encoders.STRING());

        citizens.show();

    }

}
```

This class when runs in local mode, works perfectly and returns below result.

```
 +--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|Michael : Non-Senior|
|Andy : Senior Cit...|
| Justin : Non-Senior|
+--------------------+
```

But when runs in yarn-client mode from eclipse, throws below exception:

**ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD**

Log:

```
Driver stacktrace:
17/05/08 17:58:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 2 failed: show at TestClassCastException.java:51, took 0.544088 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 6, localhost, executor 1): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2127)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2765)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2795)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:595)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:604)
    at com.demo.spark21.dataset.TestClassCastException.main(TestClassCastException.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2127)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

NB: I have set SPARK_HOME environment variable in eclipse.

Versions in pom.xml

spark - 2.1.0

scala - 2.11

The above version is same in cluster also. I have installed hadoop 2.7.3 and spark in Pseudo distributed mode in personal laptop.

Where am I missing?

Comment: Tis is just to verify something. can you take count instead of citizens.show(); ???

Comment: Might be related to [SPARK-18075](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18075): read through the comments, the bottom line is that Spark applications might not run successfully from within IDEs due to (unspecified) missing "setup" that's usually done by spark-submit.